# creating Github repo with my custom odoo module

Tags: odoo

I'm new to odoo, but I'm a node.js web developer. I'm used to developing on my local machine, pushing the code to my github repo, then cloning or pulling the code on the server.
But developing odoo is different, I cloned the odoo github repo on my local machine, developed my custom module as an addon.
So I'm wondering, do I push the whole project to my github repo, odoo repo + my custom module. Or, only push my custom module?

If I chose the first option, I'll lose any future updates to odoo repo (if I understood correctly). If chose the second option, how can I choose only my custom module from the project and push it to my github?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

From what I have done, I only maintain and push custom modules so that I can pick any module to clone/pull. The Odoo itself can be downloaded again from the source and even upgraded. This will separate Odoo standard components from custom modules. I find it easier to manage this way. However, it really depends on personal/organizational preferences.

Answer (score 0):

There are two repositories.

1. Odoo Official Repository.
2. Your Custom Modules Repository.

**Odoo Official Repository:**

Odoo is also maintaining their code on Github and it is open source(community edition) so you can download it and customize it as per your requirements `but you are not allowed to push your customization in the Odoo source code` that is why there is a concept about custom module/custom code etc.

**Your Custom Modules Repository:**

So you're not allowed to change anything in Odoo's source code but we need to customize Odoo as per our requirements so we do development and maintain separate repositories for our custom code `and you are the owner of this code.`

> So when ever you do some code or do any customization instead of
> pushing on Odoo's official repository push it in your own repository.

And while developing custom module keep them separate from Odoo's addons in separate directory. So it will become easy for you to push and take pull of your custom module.
And it will also easy to take pull from Odoo updates.

**EDIT**

Just add the custom modules' directory path in your config file.

Comment: To clarify, you should update the `addons_path` option in your Odoo configuration file. It might look like `addons_path = /path/to/odoo/addons,/path/to/odoo/custom_addons`